# Tkinter Frame object will not grid

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Running into an issue trying to grid a framed object I created in a rudimentary paint program.

The instantiation code that gets the error is here:

```
from tkinter import *
from Menu import Menu

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        #Imports each of the frames from the collection from the various widgets
        menu=Menu()
        menu.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=2)

app=Application()
app.master.title=('Sample Application')
app.mainloop()
```

The error I receive is related to the `menu=Menu()` operation and is:

```
TypeError: Menu() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Frame'
```

The `Menu` object is here:

```
from tkinter import *
import CommandStack

def Menu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.new=Button(self,command=CommandStack.new())
        self.save=Button(self,command=CommandStack.save())
        self.save.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.load=Button(self,command=CommandStack.load())
        self.load.grid(row=0,column=2)
```

My confusion is how that positional error occurs. When I give the menu a frame (`self`), the grid method instead I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

I feel liking I'm missing a key part of working with frames, but I'm not sure what. Suggestions?

Comment: Are you intending that `Menu` be a class or a function? You've defined it as a function (`def`) but implemented it like a class (`__init__`).

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want `Menu` to be a class, and therefore defined it as such with the `__init__` method. But you instead defined `Menu` to be a function, therefore all functions you stored inside are just defined as code that you would only use in the function. Change the `def Menu` to `class Menu` and it should be fine.

Comment: Youre welcome! Can you verify my answer while youre at it?